Dataclass serializer doesn't accept empty value although marked as optional
Using drf, I have a dataclass serializer.
I keep getting the error {'offer': {'service_class': [ErrorDetail(string='This field may not be blank.', code='blank')]}}
although I have marked the service_class property of the dataclass as optional
from typing import List, Optional, Union

@dataclass
class TravelOffer:
    service_class: Optional[str]
    ... (other properties)

The TravelOffer is used in my Reward class:
@dataclass
class Reward:

    offer_id: str = field(init=False)
    offer: TravelOffer



which is used for my RewardSerializer:
class RewardSerializer(DataclassSerializer):
    class Meta:
        dataclass = Reward


Anybody see anything I might be missing? As far as I can see I'm doing it exactly as the docs say.
Tried giving it a default value etc, but I still get this error

Just realised - is the problem that my TravelOffer dataclass is does not have a serializer?
If so how do you incorporate that into the serializer for the Reward?
